# Python 3 pandas dataframe creation depends on file format csv or txt

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

As a new python learner, I am working on creating dataframe depends on the file format in the dictionary.

below is the script i was working on.
So my main goal is to use if/else to conditionally execute a pd.read_csv(filename) However, I am not sure how to map the correct file to the (filename) part.

In the filename dictionary, when there is a txt format file,  I would like to execute it by using df = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter = '|')
if the file is in csv then I'd like to execute it by df = pd.read_csv(filename)
Can someone please help me what needs to be added here for the files to be mapped to the appropriate pd.read_csv option?

```
filename = ["1.txt","2.csv","3.txt","4.csv"...etc]

sub = '.csv'

for file in filename:

    if sub in file:

        df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    else:

        df = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter = '|')
```

Comment: The idea you have will work, but needs better organisation so you don't end up continually overwriting the same variable. Use a list or a dictionary to hold them.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have the right basic idea. The only thing is, you'll be creating a variable number of dataframes. For this, I'd recommend organizing it into a dictionary of dataframes.

**Example**:

say `1.txt` contains:

```
a|b|c
1|2|3
```

and `2.csv` contains:

```
a,b,c
4,5,6
```

Then you can do this:

```
filename = ["1.txt", "2.csv"]

sub = '.csv'

# Create empty dictionary
dict_of_dfs = {}

# Iterate through your files
for f in filename:
    # if .csv is found, add a dictionary key with the filename minus the extension
    # Use default delimiter
    if sub in f:
        dict_of_dfs[f[:-4]] = pd.read_csv(f)
    # For other (.txt) files, just change the delimiter
    else:
        dict_of_dfs[f[:-4]] = pd.read_csv(f, delimiter='|')
```

You'll have access to the dataframes as you would any other dictionary, just use the filename minus the extension as the key:

```
>>> dict_of_dfs['1']
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
>>> dict_of_dfs['2']
   a  b  c
0  4  5  6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can encapsulate the functionality you're looking for using `zip`, and list comprehensions:

```
# Create a list that maps the file's extension to a delimiter
delimiters = [
    None if sub in file else '|'
    for file in filename
]
# Iterate through the delimiter/file pairs produced by zip
for delimiter, file in zip(delimiters, filename):
    df = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter=delimiter)
```

If you're interested in obtaining a list of only CSV files, I would recommend using Python's `pathlib` module:

```
from pathlib import Path
here = Path('.')
csvs = [
    file for file in here.iterdir()
    if file.suffix == 'csv'
]
```

Once you have that list, you can create a list of dataframes in a list comprehension, as well.

Comment: Thanks for your input PMende. Do you know if there's a way to create a df by file format? for example, If there are multiple csv files, is there a way to create the df only for that file format?

Comment: @JungLee I've edited the answer in an attempt to address this.

Comment: thank you for your help. My last question would be, is there a way to create a script to create dataframe per file? Let's supposed there is a windowspath c:\user\ with 3 csv files and 3 txt files. [1.txt,2.txt,3.txt,4.csv,5.csv,6.csv] If I wish to create 1 to 1 dataframe in python, which iteration format should I use? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want your code to work, change `filename` to `file` in your `pd.read_csv` statements:

```
filename = ["1.txt","2.csv","3.txt","4.csv"...etc]

sub = '.csv'

for file in filename:
    if sub in file:
        df = pd.read_csv(file)
    else:
        df = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter = '|')
```

However, this will only cause `df` to be overwritten all the time, so at the end `df` will only be equal to your last file. Use the anser of **sacul** if you want to have a fully working solution.